# Why is my transaction not visible on ropsten.etherscan

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, ropsten, solc

I am testing a contract on a Ropsten network using geth 1.8.8 with command line:

```
geth --testnet --datadir=""
```

In order to connect to geth I use web3js version 1, beta 34 running from node.js.

Compiler I use is solc 4.24 release. I was able to publish the contract, where I was able to **verify source so you can see it**:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x62e461ba21ae18cd412eaa4935532da9e519f7d3

After submitting first transaction after creation geth returned the middle and next line:

```
INFO [05-30|10:31:56] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
INFO [05-30|10:31:59] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x124d796b68a454711b41fb00afda704f92e834db15d392b34857fe79c155eaa8 recipient=0x62e461Ba21AE18cd412eaA4935532Da9E519F7D3
INFO [05-30|10:32:08] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1   txs=4    mgas=0.145   elapsed=16.977ms  mgasps=8.570   number=3339069 hash=89c612…2f245e cache=21.43mB
```

More lines followed. I am kind of suspicious of the first line but I got same issue in the past even without it.
Searching for transaction returned nothing after two hours:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x124d796b68a454711b41fb00afda704f92e834db15d392b34857fe79c155eaa8

I set gas price to 4 gwei and that was a mistake on my side, but I had transactions execute regardless. I fixed it to 40 gwei and repeated transaction, new one is:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x8e5580b0b7b5b0b4e6493071363a44d59aa43321292e941b6cb057925562aaa6

First error I received in both cases was from inside my webapp soon after geth received 50 new blocks:

```
Error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
```

Let me state that this happens relatively often even with a stable internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I had to reduce value I added to nonce from 100 back to 0.